# Include.jsp file not found

Tags: java

I am a beginner in openmrs developping. I work in a project in with we have download the **openmrs** and import it in **eclipse** using **github repository**. If I try to run the project it shows:

> include.jsp file not found.

please help to fix the error.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your code? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you have a file Include.jsp? Is it in the right directory? We can only guess solutions if you don't tell us more.

Comment: I think first you need to share your code which produces this error, without any code or source how other people help you?